# Get the src of the image field in a view in drupal

Tags: drupal-views, drupal-7

We were working with Drupal 7 and trying to rewrite the views output

We need the src of the image field , not the whole image tag.

Clicking on

Rewrite the output of this field

`[field_first_image]` : Gives the whole content ie with  tag ,

We tried to display the below ones

`[field_first_image-fid]` == Raw fid

`[field_first_image-alt]` == Raw alt

`[field_first_image-title]` == Raw title

But the same ( [field_first_image-fid] ) thing is displayed in the view. Is there a way we can get the src from the views rewrite ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the file name by changing the field as shown in the attached image.

Formatter: Rendered file

View mode: Tokens (or Link will work - depending on what modules you have installed)

Strip HTML tags (checked)

You'd then need to do a Rewrite Output with the server's public file location in front of the token [field_first_image]. That'll get you the full SRC.

There's probably a better way to do this though... Depending on the final thing you're attempting to create.

[image: Views settings]

Comment: I don't really know whether this is right answer for I don't play with Drupal now adays. If your answer is right I can mark it as yes. So for that I will wait for some one to vote for the answer. If anyone gets a vote I will surely mark it as right. So I/you don't write something wrong. Hope that makes sense. Thank you once again for the answer.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want to need to install a module for this, there is a solution.

- Create a new relationship
- Select your image field (this will create a relationship to the file entity)
- Add a field to your view
- Select `File: Path`
- Check `Display download path instead of file storage URI`

Note that this will create a URL to the original image, not to an image produced when applying an image style (like cropping, resizing etc.) so this may not work in every scenario.

Comment: To get the uri of the file just don't check the `Display download path instead of file storage URI`.

Comment: If you wan't internal link (public://), you have to uncheck it. If you want the full path, you need to check on this option.. So it's a correct! This worked for me!

Answer (score 18):

[Image URL Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter)

This module add a url formatter for image field. Then you can output image url directly.

Comment: Plain and simple. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to create a custom field formatter for the image field and use this formatter in the set-up of the view.

In your case, the custom image field formatter shall only return the source of the src of the image.

You can use this great tutorial to create a custom field formatter : http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/creating-new-field-formatters-drupal-7